Interlink WooCommerce products between them for cross sells settings
In WooCommerce, I would like:

if Product A is added in the cross sells of Product B, then Product B should also automatically be added in the cross sells of Product A.
if Product A is removed from the cross sells of Product B, then Product B should also automatically be removed from the cross sells of Product A.

This is the code that I have:
add_action('save_post_product', 'auto_link_cross_sells', 20, 2);

function auto_link_cross_sells($post_id, $post) {
    // Prevent infinite loop using a transient
    if (get_transient('auto_cross_sell_processing')) {
        return;
    }

    // Get the current product's cross-sell IDs
    $cross_sell_ids = get_post_meta($post_id, '_crosssell_ids', true);

    // If there are no cross-sell IDs, exit the function
    if (empty($cross_sell_ids) || !is_array($cross_sell_ids)) {
        return;
    }

    // Set a transient to prevent an infinite loop
    set_transient('auto_cross_sell_processing', true, 10);

    // Loop through each cross-sell product ID
    foreach ($cross_sell_ids as $cross_sell_id) {
        // Check if the cross-sell product ID is valid
        if (!get_post($cross_sell_id)) {
            continue;
        }

        // Get the existing cross-sell IDs for the cross-sell product
        $existing_cross_sells = get_post_meta($cross_sell_id, '_crosssell_ids', true);
        if (!is_array($existing_cross_sells)) {
            $existing_cross_sells = [];
        }

        // If the current product is not already a cross-sell of the cross-sell product, add it
        if (!in_array($post_id, $existing_cross_sells)) {
            $existing_cross_sells[] = $post_id;
            update_post_meta($cross_sell_id, '_crosssell_ids', $existing_cross_sells);
        }
    }

    // Remove the transient to allow the function to run again later
    delete_transient('auto_cross_sell_processing');
}

But it still doesn't do the job.

There are some missing things in your code, as what you are trying to do is more complicated than you thought.
Also, since WooCommerce 3, you should better use WC_Product available methods than WordPress Post Meta functions, as WooCommerce uses custom database tables.
Here we need to use a custom field to keep track of previous history, allowing to process removed Cross-Sell IDS.
Try the following code instead, that should process and interlink cross-sells between products:
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'process_interlinked_product_cross_sells', 100 );
function process_interlinked_product_cross_sells( $post_id ) {
    // Get current WC_Product object
    $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );

    // Get the current product cross-sell IDs
    $cross_sell_ids = (array) $product->get_cross_sell_ids();
    
    // Get current product cross-sell IDs previous history track
    $previous_cs_ids = (array) $product->get_meta('_previous_cs_ids');

    // Check differences related to history
    $differences_add    = array_diff($cross_sell_ids, $previous_cs_ids); 
    $differences_remove = array_diff($previous_cs_ids, $cross_sell_ids);

    // Added IDS case
    if ( count($differences_add) > 0 ) {
        // Loop through product cross-sell IDs (added)
        foreach ( $differences_add as $cross_sell_id ) {
            // get the WC_Product object from current cross sell ID
            $_product = wc_get_product( $cross_sell_id ); 

            if ( ! $_product ) continue;

            // Get cross-sell IDs for the cross-sell product
            $_cross_sell_ids = (array) $_product->get_cross_sell_ids();

            if ( ! in_array( $post_id, $_cross_sell_ids  ) ) {
                $_cross_sell_ids[] = $post_id; // Add the initial current product Id to the array
                $_product->set_cross_sell_ids( $_cross_sell_ids ); // Set updated cross-sells Ids
                $_product->update_meta_data( '_previous_cs_ids', $_cross_sell_ids ?: '' ); // Update history
                $_product->save(); // Sync and save
            }
        }
    }

    // Removed IDS case
    if ( count($differences_remove) > 0 ) {
        // Loop through product cross-sell IDs (removed)
        foreach ( $differences_remove as $key => $cross_sell_id ) {
            // get the WC_Product object from current cross sell ID
            $_product = wc_get_product( $cross_sell_id ); 

            if ( ! $_product ) continue;

            // Get cross-sell IDs for the cross-sell product
            $_cross_sell_ids = (array) $_product->get_cross_sell_ids();
            
            if ( in_array( $post_id, $_cross_sell_ids  ) ) {
                // Remove the initial current product Id from the array
                unset($_cross_sell_ids[$key]); 
                
                $_product->set_cross_sell_ids( $_cross_sell_ids ); // Set updated cross-sells Ids
                $_product->update_meta_data( '_previous_cs_ids', $_cross_sell_ids ?: '' ); // Update history track
                $_product->save(); // Sync and save
            }
        }
    }

    // Update current product history track
    if ( count($differences_add) > 0 || count($differences_remove) > 0 ) {
        $product->update_meta_data( '_previous_cs_ids', $cross_sell_ids ?: '' ); // Update history track
        $product->save();// Sync and save
    }
}

Tested and works.

Hi @LoicTheAztec, thanks for the code, I've tested it but after updating a product, I'm getting a fatal error unfortunately. https://jeriss.tinytake.com/msc/MTAxMjQ3NTBfMjM4MDAwMjU

Here is a link to the error log file : https://jeriss.tinytake.com/msc/MTAxMjQ5MTdfMjM4MDAyMDc

Oups!, sorry, my fault: The function name was named differently in the add_action(). I have updated my answer code.

Hi @Loic, I've tried as well the updated code but still getting fatal error upon updating a product. Here is the link to the error log file : https://jeriss.tinytake.com/msc/MTAxMjUzMTlfMjM4MDA2OTk

PHP Error : Enclosed '{' does not match ')' => screenshot https://jeriss.tinytake.com/msc/MTAxMzkzNTlfMjM4MTU1NjU

There was a PHP error and I was able to identify the issue. I removed the extra ); on line 8 which I removed and now it works fine. Thanks for the help!

@JerissCloudCenter Updated… Sorry, ); was a remaining from an error_log(); function that I have removed partially directly from the code in here… The important thing is that the code works.
